# Sending more than 20Bytes over BLE

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Once again I am asking for support regarding BlueTooth Low Energy.
My goal is to send 79 Byte over BLE. The sending device is a TI CC2650LP and the receiving device is a Win10 PC using WinRT API.
After some research I found that the best solution is to split the message into 20Byte chunks and send them with a little delay in the same characteristic. That doesn't seem to be a problem.
My question now is: How can i receive this split up data and join it up to a 79Byte message again?
Is there a way to just wait until everything is transmitted? How can I make the code know when to start and when to stop?
My code for reading a single characteristic works with valuechaged events and a datareader:

```
        public void currentSelectedCharacteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue);
        reader.ReadBytes(ret);           
    }
```

There seems to be very little documentation about this issue online and most of it is for Android devices.

Another approach would be using 4 different characteristic, waiting for 1 notification and reading them out at once. But the reading part seems difficult in this scenario, because the valuechanged event only triggers for 1 characteristic

Comment: What programming language is this? It's certainly not C++.

Comment: You are absolutely right, It is C#. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is too long to be read with a single read, most libraries enable the offset along with the handle to be sent in the request, so that the characteristic value can be read in successive chunks. Multiple request/response pairs might be required, depending on the length of the attribute value being read.

I am not familiar with the WinRT or TI API's.

A quick browse of the WinRT documentation seems to show that GattReadRequestedEventArgs Class has GattReadRequest Class which has a property called [offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattreadrequest?view=winrt-19041#properties). This is how you know which chunk it is.

On the TI side, it seems to be [GATT_WriteLongCharValue()](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru393e/swru393e.pdf?ts=1597743720411&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and [GATT_ReadLongCharValue()](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru393e/swru393e.pdf?ts=1597743720411&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Comment: @ ukBaz The GATT_WriteLongCharValue() function seems to be what I was looking for. 
There is very little documentation about how the function call works in detail, so im gonna ask here: How do I get the connhandle and the task parameters? For the Task parameter I saw 'selfEntity' being used. Is that universally useable? A piece of Code would be fine too

Comment: I would expect you to get more help on the TI support forum: https://e2e.ti.com/search?q=GATT_WriteLongCharValue&category=forum